# whats the best practice or rule to write the if condition or block in smarty template?

Tags: php, if-statement, smarty

When I am writing my if block open and close in one line then it creates a problem while printing the variable, but not when I am using like this:

```
{if isset($title)}
  {$title}
{/if}
```

Problem with:

```
{if isset($title)}{$title}{/if}
```

if I use the code in single line the variable prints unnecessary spaces at the end of string, I have tried by using strip and trim but no use.

**What's the reason behind this problem?**

Comment: If I'm the next developer I would have preferred a more reading friendly pattern. The first one.

Comment: But why my second code is giving wrong output?

Comment: Not sure about that one but I would ask it in their forum for a faster reply. My guess would be a conflict with the braces.

Comment: Posted here: https://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=27275